# How to generate Long type variable in API spec generated by FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, openapi-generator

This class is a part of a project:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, StrictInt, constr, validator


class Person(BaseModel):
    person_id: StrictInt
    person_name: constr(strip_whitespace=True, strict=True)

    @validator('person_id')
    def person_id_validator(cls, val):
        assert val is not None
        return val

    @validator('person_name')
    def person_name_validator(cls, val):
        assert val != ''
        return val
```

When the API-spec is generated for this class using `FastAPI().openapi()`, the type of the variable `person_id` is always `integer` and consequently, the Java client generated from that spec always has the wrapper class `Integer` for the variable `personId`. However, `personId` can be a very long number (>5,000,000,000) which I can't keep in an `Integer`.

Pydantic itself doesn't have a `Long` built-in. Python handles int32 and int64 internally so I cannot control that either. I tried using `numpy.int64` and `torch.long` with the help of `arbitrary_types_allowed` in `class Config` but that always fails at runtime with the message
`ValueError: Value not declarable with JSON Schema, field: name='person_id' type=int64 required=True`.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: OpenAPI Spec uses `type: integer` + [`format: int64`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#numbers) to define longs. Does something like `person_id: StrictInt = Field(..., format='int64')` or `person_id: StrictInt = Field(..., json_schema_extra={format='int64'})` work?

Comment: @Helen Tested. `Field(..., format="int64")` is correct! The latter with `json_schema_extra` does not (syntax problems aside) in v1, but might in v2. I think your comment nevertheless deserves to be turned into a proper answer because this is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OpenAPI, long integers are defined as:

```yaml
type: integer
format: int64
```

The key is to use the proper `format`. When using FastAPI/Pydantic, you can add the `format` attribute as follows:

```py
person_id: StrictInt = Field(..., format='int64')
```